Shell concatenate text file (json) into string argument
I have a working command:
mycommand --environment '{"Variables":{"var1":"new_val1","var2":"new_val2"}}'

However, I want to place {"var1":"new_val1","var2":"new_val2"} in a json file (vars.json) and have the command read it on the fly.
I've tried using cat:
mycommand --environment '{"Variables":' + cat vars.json + '}'

This results in error: Unknown options: cat, vars.json, +, }, +
vars.json contains:
{"var1":"new_val1","var2":"new_val2"}

How can I concatenate the content of vars.json into the '{"Variables":...'}' string?

Try mycommand --environment '{"Variables":'"$(cat vars.json)"'}' (no spaces between ' and ". Or use jq: mycommand --environment "$(jq '{Variables: .}' vars.json)"

@pmf that works. Post an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Does this really need an answer? This is basic shell syntax for substituting the output of a command. There have been plenty of similar questions in the past.

I'd use $(< filename) instead of $(cat filename) in bash.
